# How to get the value type for class with static members

Tags: typescript, typescript-class

Let's say I have a class like this

```
class StaticClass {
  static readonly HELLO = 1
  static readonly WORLD = 2
}
```

How can i access the values of the static class as a type such that the result would be as such.

```
type ValueOfStaticClassMember = 1 | 2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the type of the `StaticClass` object itself via `typeof StaticClass`. Then your task is to remove the `prototype` property and (I'm guessing) any static methods so we're left only with static properties. You can do that with a mapped type where you map the key `prototype` and any key referring to a function to `never` (so it doesn't show up in the resulting type), like this:

```typescript
class StaticClass {
    static readonly HELLO = 1
    static readonly WORLD = 2
    static method() {} // Added this just to ensure it didn't come through
}

type ClassStaticProperties<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T as Key extends "prototype" ? never : T[Key] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? never : Key]: T[Key];
}

type StaticProperties = ClassStaticProperties<typeof StaticClass>;
//   ^? type StaticProperties = { readonly HELLO: 1; readonly WORLD: 2; }
type ValueOfStaticClassMember = StaticProperties[keyof StaticProperties];
//   ^? type ValueOfStaticClassmember = 1 | 2
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKAuZ4EtgGFxWgbwLAChojoJEVhoAnAUzABMB7AOxAE9oAJAUQBkeB5aAF5oARgLESZVFVqMW7AOr8ASjwAiw6ACYJxUkhkBbavAAWDOgAoAlDgC+0APRPoAQTp1qdaOeQwAKwBXUl8GaGomCCCaaGR4aDpkOiYAcgTgBhNfM0oGIIBzMwJ7AgJ4VgAHamgMSAgEQ2AABTzqyhRqCAAeABUAPi08QmIAbQBpanZkJmgAaymGADNoXuhIaEn2agAPeEi6GAAiSrz4Bgrqo+gAfmgmagA3akpoAC5ViamAXQi9g5gVgAdCCwJQChAPmAmKxRt87EJBtD2HcHs9Xh8tt8Pr0vqxvgBuEplfCXGqNcitBjtTowER1KAU1BUmnILrdMnLODSdCYCD9In4FzEAB6N3KVRqADUwCAgtR+Esmbz6gBZahGABGLy0ypZL1powWrC5eraBrZEEJBGFRDFQA)

If you **do** want to include static methods, just remove the second conditional from the key:

```typescript
type ClassStaticMembers<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T as Key extends "prototype" ? never : Key]: T[Key];
}
type StaticMembers = ClassStaticMembers<typeof StaticClass>;
//   ^? type StaticMembers = { readonly HELLO: 1; readonly WORLD: 2; method: () => void; }
type ValueOfStaticClassMember = StaticMembers[keyof StaticMembers];
//   ^? type ValueOfStaticClassMember = 1 | 2 | (() => void)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKAuZ4EtgGFxWgbwLAChojoJEVhoAnAUzABMB7AOxAE9oAJAUQBkeB5aAF5oARgLESZVFVqMW7AOr8ASjwAiw6ACYJxUkhkBbavAAWDOgAoAlDgC+0APRPoAQTp1qdaOeQwAKwBXUl8GaGomCCCaaGR4aDpkOiYAcgTgBhNfM0oGIIBzMwJ7AgJ4VgAHamgMSAgEQ2AAWWojACNqSggAHgAVAD4tPEJiAG0AaWp2ZCZoAGtphgAzaD7oSGgp9moAD3hIuhgAIkq8+AYK6uPoAH5oJmoANy7oAC4t6YBdD77J74A3CUyvgrjVGuRWh0ujARHUoBDUFDOt0emCVnBpOhMBABkD8C5iAA9W7lKo1ABqYBAQWo-GWiOx9WRrxEjJZ3TGi1YGPZbRREC++MJRBJBCAA)